# Prove that a norm makes a space Banach

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, banach-algebras, cauchy-sequences

I have to prove that if $A$ is a C*-Algebra then the algebra $A_1$ obtained adjoining the identity is a C*Algebra too (with the usual algebraic operation defined).

I have any problem in all the points of the proof but in one: to prove that the new space is Banach.

The norm in the new space is defined to be:

$\|a+\alpha\|= \sup\{\|ax + \alpha x\|: x\in A, \|x\|\leq 1\}$

I have to prove that every cauchy sequence $(a_n+\alpha_n)_n$ is convergent.
Intuitively it exist a limit for $a_n$ that is $a$, and a limit for $\alpha_n$, that is $\alpha$. Then I have to show that $\lim \sup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\{\|a_nx + \alpha_n x -ax - \alpha x\|: x\in A, \|x\|\leq 1\}=0$. But the formal proof escapes me. Can you give me a little help? Thanks.

Comment: Why not use the norm $||a+\alpha|| = ||a|| + |\alpha|$? Also, your definition is circular, or at least the notation has a problem, because when $x=1$ in a term on the right side you get the number on the left side as a special case.

Comment: $A$ in general has no identity, so $x$ cannot be $1$.

Comment: @KCd: I think maybe there is an implicit assumption that A is not unital.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Anyway, my first sentence still stands: why not use that simpler formula for your norm?

Comment: Ok, if I take your first advice I have a norm that makes simpler to prove that $A_1$ is a Banach algebra, but I'm taking this suggestion from Conway, that soon after uses the norm I've stated to prove the property of the C*Algebras $\|y^\ast y\|=\|y\|^2$ that I can't prove using the norm you suggest (I think).

Comment: There's a very veeeery good treatment of precisely this issue in section 1.3. of Erdos' C*-algebras: http://www.mth.kcl.ac.uk/~jerdos/CS/CS.pdf

Comment: @KCd: The norm is unique in a C*-algebra. Choosing an equivalent norm then fails to satisfy the C*-property. The norm chosen above is precisely(!) the right norm that makes this a C*-algebra.

Comment: @Freeze_S: Oh, I see. I was unaware of that (I don't work on C*-algebras).